# How to remove all files in a Git repository that are not in the working directory?

Tags: git

I'm in the process of splitting up an old suite of applications which originally resided in a single Subversion repository.

I've converted it over to a Git repository and removed what I don't want, but I'd like to slim the repository down by getting rid of the historical data associated with the deleted files (the original repository will be maintained for reference purposes so it isn't needed in the new one).

Ideally what I'd like to do is go through the entire repository and remove any files or folders not present in the working directory, along with any history associated with them. This would leave me with the contents of HEAD and a history of commits affecting those files. However, I haven't come across a way of doing this (orphaning HEAD doesn't help as it doesn't preserve the history).

Is this possible? I know how to remove a single file or folder from the entire history via git-filter-branch, but there's too many files and folders for this to be a practical approach... unless there's a way of filtering on all files not in HEAD?

Comment: What about files that got renamed in the past? Strip history when the rename occurred or keep the rename (and track a different filename previous to the rename)

Comment: Good point. I'd prefer to keep the history prior to the rename, so there'd need to be a few extra files in there which is fine.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you can use git filter-branch to get rid of all files that you don't want:

1. Get a list of the filenames that you don't want to appear in the history both the old names and the new names in case of renames. For example put them in a file called toberemoved.txt
2. Run git filter-branch like this:

   ```
   $ git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f `cat toberemoved.txt`" branch1 branch2 ...
   ```

Here's the relevant man page from git filter-branch:

```
   --tree-filter <command>
       This is the filter for rewriting the tree and its contents. The
       argument is evaluated in shell with the working directory set to
       the root of the checked out tree. The new tree is then used as-is
       (new files are auto-added, disappeared files are auto-removed -
       neither .gitignore files nor any other ignore rules HAVE ANY
       EFFECT!).
```

So just make sure that the list of files you want deleted are all relative to the root of the checked out tree.

Update:

To get the list of the files that were present in the past but not in the current working directory you can run the following.  Note that you'll have to do further effort to keep the "history before renaming" of renamed files:

```
$ git log --raw |awk '/^:/ { if (! printed[$6]) { print $6; printed[$6] = 1 }}'|while read f;do if [ ! -f $f ]; then echo Deleted: $f;fi;done
```

That $6 is the name of the file that were affected in a commit in shown in the --raw mode of log.

See the --diff-filter option to git log if you want know what happened ([D]eleted, [R]enamed, [M]odified, and so on) to each file for every commit.

Maybe others can chime in on how to find out the previous name of a tracked file in case of renames.

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. Getting closer I think, I hadn't thought about using `cat` with filter-branch. The bit I still don't get however is how to generate the list of files, given that I'm only interested in removing files *not* in the working directory (and hence not readily available to list). Any further ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the command to get a list of deleted files.

Comment: Nice answer. I removed `Deleted: ` from the oneliner to get the list.  But when using that list, for some reason the bash syntax in the git filter-branch command didn't work. So, instead I used `git filter-branch --tree-filter "cat $HOME/toberemoved.txt | xargs -I{} rm -f {}"` (Note that `toberemoved.txt` needed to be outside the dir under version control. It's possible this caused the issue with the `"cat `toberemoved.txt`"` syntax too but I haven't checked.)

Answer (score 3):

I did this a couple of times - extract commits for a single file and create new repository from them. It goes somewhat like this:

```
$ c=10; for commit in $(git log --format=%h -- path/to/file|tac); do
      c=$((c+1))
      git format-patch -1 --stdout $commit > $c.patch
  done
```

This creates the patch files 11.patch, 12.patch and so on. I then edit these patches (using vim or perl whichever seems best for the job), removing entire hunks for files that I'm not interested in, and maybe fix the names as well in case of renames in the diff hunk header.

The I'd use git am on the patches on a new git repository. If something doesn't come up right then I nuke the new git repository and edit the patches again and repeat the git am.

The reason I start counting from 10 is because I'm lazy to prepend a leading 0 to the patch sequence and for commits more than 99 I just start at 99.

Comment: you could use `$(printf "%02d" $c).patch` to prepend a leading zero.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I must start using printf more often from now on.

Comment: Thanks... but does this not work on a file by file basis though? As I said in my question, I know how to do it on a per-file basis, but there's too many files for that to be practical. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what's happening here?

Comment: Ah in that case you can use git filter-branch. I'll put that as another answer in a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Helping to the second answer: *"Maybe others can chime in on how to find out the previous name of a tracked file in case of renames."*

This will return the files in your project and the files from which they are renamed.

`` for file in `git ls-files`; do git log --follow --name-only --pretty=format: $file | sort -n -b | uniq | sed '/^\s*$/d'; done ``

You can use them to exclude from the list.

The whole solution is:

`` for file in `git ls-files`; do git log --follow --name-only --pretty=format: $file | sort -n -b | uniq | sed '/^\s*$/d'; done > current.txt ``

`git log --raw |awk '/^:/ { if (! printed[$6]) { print $6; printed[$6] = 1 }}'|while read f;do if [ ! -f $f ]; then echo $f;fi;done | sort > hist.txt`

`diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format=""  hist.txt current.txt > for_remove.txt`