# Git: rm files not in currenty working directory (With cmd/batch)

Tags: git, version-control

I want to create a repository for a games mod's and want us to always have the same mods. We both run windows so I figured I use a batch file. (Also open about better alternatives for that if you know one! :) )

He does not understand Git at all so I want Git to rm the files that he deleted in his working directory when commiting.

I found one solution with a very similar problem and solution here on stackoverflow but it didn't work on Windows/Cmd. -> [How to remove all files in a Git repository that are not in the working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336252/how-to-remove-all-files-in-a-git-repository-that-are-not-in-the-working-director)